# FIFO-property in graphs

Tags: graph, fifo

Routing, Time-Dependent Graphs, FIFO, NON-FIFO

Hello,

I read alot in literature about the FIFO-property in Time-Dependent graphs.
The FIFO property ensures that the temporal sequence of departures is mirrored in the sequence of arrivals, maintaining chronological consistency.

Now in my network, it is possible to (1) depart later and arrive at the same time. But you (2) can't depart later and arrive earlier.

So (1) is basically an edge case. My question is: does the FIFO-property hold in this case or not? And would it matter for Time-Dependent Dijkstra